# Jasmine in Angular 2+ No specs found

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

When I run `ng test` Karma opens Jasmine in Chrome with the following message:

> Incomplete: No specs found

The Karma window looks like so:

[image: Karma window]

My `karma.conf.js` is pretty standard:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/malbet'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

My `src/test.ts` file is also standard:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: any;
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
context.keys().map(context);
```

Is the error likely to be in these two configuration files or would it be a problem with how I introduce the tests in the component's `xxx.spec.ts` file?

Comment: I'm using Angular 8 with standard files `karma.conf.js` and `test.ts` in the `src/` folder (see https://angular.io/guide/testing#configuration). Where does `test.js` come from?

Comment: @uminder my bad, it is indeed `test.ts`. The `js` suffix was my typo. I have corrected the question.

Comment: @uminder yes. An example would be `src/app/shopping/shopping.component.spec.ts`. That spec file is importing the necessary from `@angular/core/testing` and creating a test suite using `decribe()` with spec tests using `it()`.

Comment: Seems unlikely that your issue is with your config files since they're basically unchanged from a new application.  Do you have any errors logged in your dev tools console in Chrome?  Maybe post a spec file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've got to the bottom of this. Jasmine was not getting far enough to run the tests because the build included a type error.

I had assumed that such an error would not cause Jasmine to give what looked like a failure. I suppose it did not get round to running any tests. Now that I have corrected the type error Jasmine is returning a list of unit test errors.